# Remove subfolder in a path with unknown/variable folder

Tags: loops, batch-file, subdirectory

I'm trying to remove:

```
C:\Users\abc01\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox
```

where `abc01` = username. So multiple `C:\users\...` folders. Some which have the "Firefox" subfolder, some who do not.

I'm trying to work out a loop to make it work but I'm having trouble.

If wildcard was usable with the RD command it would be:

```
rd /q /s "C:\Users\\*\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox"
```

Thank you very much for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use wild-cards like `*` or `?` in the middle of a path, they may orruc only in the last element. A work-around is to use a [`for /D` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) to resolve the wild-card, then do the sub-folder deletion in the body of the loop, like this:

```cmd
for /D %%D in ("C:\Users\*") do (
    rd /Q /S "%%~D\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox"
)
```

Comment: Ah! This is exactly what i was trying to achieve, thank you very much! I was using a For /f loop and processing the results, too complicated while this does it nicely. :)